# Why we need OKTA in our application for auth or authentication purpose?

Tags: authentication, okta

I want to know why we need OKTA in our application (of course I mean a case when we want to use it for our login or auth purpose). My question is why we can't just use google accounts to connect with our application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sure can integrate with Google. Okta is just one of multiple identity providers in the market, including Auth0, OneLogin, Ping, etc.

One of the reasons might be, that it's specializing in identity and access management, so they developed pretty good APIs around that. Also they can help you to manage access to multiple applications (if you have more than one), they have directory integrations (AD/LDAP), sign-in widget, OIDC/SAML/WSFED support... So you see where I'm going hopefully. They have extras, which make it not exactly apple to apple comparison to Google.

I won't go into more details here, as to be honest, it's not exactly a question for SO, as it's opinionated and can't be answered precisely.